# Апдейт поля с добавлением тайизоны к дате

Tags: sql, postgresql

В базе данных ранее поле содержало только дату, далее были внесены правки и теперь данное поле содержит так же и таймзону. У старых записей необходимо проапдейтить данное поле так, что бы дата осталась той же, что указано, но к ней добавилась таймзона, подскажите как это можно реализовать? или что можно почитать касаемо этого?

Comment: В базу пишет данные приложение. Формат поля был изменен и теперь туда пишется дата с таймзоной, но вот старые записи так и остались в прежнем виде и поэтому мне нужно их проапдейтить, что бы привести к общему виду.

Comment: В общих словах ситуация такая. Приложение складывает данные в бд в несколько таблиц. Ранее приложение складывало json кусками в определенные поля таблицы. Дата в это json была вида 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000, теперь складывает так:  2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+03, мне необходимо к старым записям добавить часовой пояс.

Comment: *что можно почитать касаемо этого?* https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT и https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

Comment: Это в отдельном поле, а как поменять это значение в куске json, там тип поля jsonb. Ранее для внесения изменений различного рода применяли функцию jsonb

Comment: Не понял... у Вас не поле, а в jsonb-значении надо менять? так это ж совсем другая задача. Ну тогда просто пройдитесь регуляркой по своим json-ам, преобразованным в текст, добавьте зону, и преобразуйте обратно.

Comment: Мне нужно и в таких поля апдейт сделать и в jsonb

Comment: Можете пример показать пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Дата в это json была вида 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000, теперь складывает так: 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+03, мне необходимо к старым записям добавить часовой пояс. – Лидия

```sql
UPDATE test
SET data = REGEXP_REPLACE(data::TEXT, '(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3})', '\1+03', 'g')::JSONB
WHERE data::TEXT !~ '\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}\+\d\d';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de04b169fed3cd9a05eaf87724f88c84

WHERE не позволяет повторно добавить зону.

Comment: Разобралась, спасибо!